# Weird Cross-origin request issue with socket.io on Openshift

Tags: node.js, sockets, cross-domain, socket.io

My application works perfectly on localhost, but when I push it to OpenShift, I'm encountering this issue with socket.io

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test-jackguy.rhcloud.com:8000/socket.io/1/?t=1387836069741. Origin http://test-jackguy.rhcloud.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I don't see why that would be an Access-control-allow-origin issue. Per OpenShift's instructions for WebSockets, I'm using the following URL on the client:

```
var socket = io.connect('ws://test-jackguy.rhcloud.com:8000/');
```

On the server I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080, process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP || process.env.NODEJS_IP);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, { log: false });
    io.set('log level', 1);
    io.set("transports", ["websocket"]);
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
/application
    server.js
    /public
        /slsd
            index.html
            /js
                script.js
```

Where script.js is the client-side connection and server.js is the server file.

Here's the URL. http://test-jackguy.rhcloud.com/slsd/ Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: If the website is temporarily down, it's because I'm pushing attempts to fix it.

Comment: Your site is being served from port 80, but you are trying to connect to the websocket server on port 8000, so the origin is different. Why do you have them on two separate ports?

Comment: According to OpenShift's documentation, websockets only functions on port 8000. The code above doesn't accurately reflect mine- I changed it. By the way, the application is now functioning using XHR-polling, which doesn't have to operate on a specific port. I'd still like to use WebSockets though.

Comment: I don't know anything about OpenShift, so I can't really comment on what the correct way to do it is for them. Everything has a port, XHR polling just uses the default port 80 like anything else unless told otherwise.

Comment: I've never had issues with it before- I had another application on OpenShift where websockets worked perfectly. Oh well, I guess.

Comment: @OP I have stumbled upon the same issue and am struggling to make it work, did you happen to find a solution by any chance?

Comment: I ended up using socket.io and its XHR polling. It's crude, but I couldn't get websockets to work.